# Save xcdatamodel automatically in the cloud

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud, cloudkit

In my app I use CoreData to store local data.
All I want is to automatically upload the xcdatamodel in the cloud so the user who delete the app and download it again will have all his data back.

I read somewhere I have only to activate the iCloud capabilities (CloudKit.framework) and all will be in the cloud.

But When I go to the dashboard there is no data, so is it simple or not to synchronize only the xcdatamodel ?

Comment: What you've read is wrong. Core Data and CloudKit are not related. You can use deprecated `CoreData iCloud` – which is **not** based on CloudKit – or you can use solutions like `Seam` or you have to write the interface yourself.

Comment: Vandian is correct.  Cloud syncing doesn't work by uploading your xcdatamodel file, you have to either use an existing solution to help or do all the coding yourself leveraging CloudKit (a large undertaking).